# Neo4j - export cypher query file results to .csv or .txt file via the Neo4jShell

Tags: shell, csv, neo4j, pipe, cypher

I have a .cql query file that I want to run from the Neo4jShell (Windows) with the command:

```
Neo4j> Neo4jShell -file query.cql
```

The query returns some rows of data. How can I write that query output into a .csv or .txt file from the shell?

Also, I am using the Windows command prompt so take that into consideration with any solutions. Thanks!

UPDATE 1:

The command suggested by Luane essentially works:

```
Neo4j> Neo4jShell -file query.cql > out.csv
```

The only issue is that the output isn't comma separated:

```
+--------------------------+
| column 1    | column 2   |
+--------------------------+
| "C1611640"  | "C1265875" |
| "C1579268"  | "C1265875" |
| "C1570906"  | "C1265875" |
| "C1522577"  | "C1265875" |
| "C1519033"  | "C1265875" |
| "C1515119"  | "C1265875" |
|      .             .     |
|      .             .     |
|      .             .     |
| "C1533658"  | "C1265875" |
| "C1532338"  | "C1265875" |
| "C1527144"  | "C1265875" |
+--------------------------+
2000 rows
219 ms
```

Comment: Have you read this: http://neo4j.com/blog/export-csv-from-neo4j-curl-cypher-jq/

Comment: Yeah, I have. I'm not sure if it works with .cql query files though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming your query returns data in the format you require, you can just send the output to any file. This works on MacOS, but I don't see why it should not work on Windows:

```
> neo4j-shell -file query.cql > out.txt
```

Comment: This essentially works. The output isn't comma separated (updated answer with output) but I should be able to write a python script to convert it to comma separated relatively easily. I'll leave the question open for a little while just in case there is a solution that directly translates the output to csv. Thanks though!

Comment: Well, you could use standard unix text processing processing commands, although it might get ugly depending on what your data actually looks like.  For example: neo4j-shell -file query.cql | awk -F\| '{print $2","$3}' > out.csv  would get you mostly there.